# Can I bind a multidimensional list to a DevExpress dataGrid?: List<List<object>>

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid, devexpress

If I have a list like this:

**list**

```
BindingList<BindingList<Message>> Messages = new BindingList<BindingList<Message>>();
Messages.Add(new BindingList<Message>() { new Message("hello", "userName", new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)) });
Messages.Add(new BindingList<Message>() { new Message("This is a message", "mister obvious", new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)) });
Messages.Add(new BindingList<Message>() { new Message("Hellow sappo", "pipo", new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)) });
Messages.Add(new BindingList<Message>() { new Message("deathstar message", "darthvader", new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)) });
```

**Message object**

```
    class Message { 
        string msg;
        string Sender;
        DateTime senddate;

        public Message(string msg, string Sender, DateTime senddate)
        {
            this.msg = msg;
            this.Sender = Sender;
            this.senddate = senddate;
        }

        public string message {
            get { return msg; }
        }
        public string sendInfo {
            get { return Sender +" | " + senddate.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

Can I bind it to a DevExpress datagrid? I want to create something like this with the datagrid:

[image]

I don't know how to do this (if it is even possible). So far I only made datagrids like this:

[image]

Comment: How would it work? Do you want to flatten `BindingList<BindingList<Message>>` into `BindingList<Message>` and display that?

Comment: I want to create a datagrid like displayed in the first image. Bud I don't know how to do it and/ or how I should build a list which I can bind in a proper way.

Comment: Your image would suggest flat list where one item is one `Message` yet you have list of list of `Message`. Hence my question do you want to flatten it first or I understand it wrong?

Comment: Well so long as you know how to create the view displayed in the image I don't care how the list is structured so long as your solution works. I made the list with the idea that the main list represents the parent table and the sublist represents the child table in each row of the parent table.

Comment: Next question then. Do you need to be able to select `Message` or this is just display?

Comment: Its just for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevEx Grid support Master-Detail rows.
This [link](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11834) has more details. Might help.

Comment: Thanks I shall take a look into Master-Detail rows. So far as I have read this page http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument783 its what I need.